# C# Regex to remove appropriate part of text

Tags: c#, regex

I have two subsequently repeating texts in "<>". The text is dynamic and has the following pattern:

```
"some text <text1> <text2> some text"
```

Based on the condition I need to remove either first or second text in "<>". I also need to remove any brackets.

Example:

```
"The company <is> <is not> a co-owner of other accounts in the Bank."
```

if true condition:

```
"The company is a co-owner of other accounts in the Bank."
```

if false condition:

```
"The company is not a co-owner of other accounts in the Bank."
```

I'd appreciate your help with regex pattern.

Comment: need more info buddy

Comment: Where does the example string actually come from? it would be much easier/better to use a `string.Format` if that is an option. Other than that, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var isTrue = true;
var str = "The company <is> <is not> a co-owner of other accounts in the Bank.";
var segment = Regex.Match(str, @"<(.*?)>\W<(.*?)>");
var replacement = str.Replace(segment.Value, isTrue ? segment.Groups[1].Value : segment.Groups[2].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example:

```
bool condition = true;
string str = (condition) ? "$2" : "$5";
var text = "some text <trueString> <falseString> some text";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, "(<)([^<>]*)(>).*?(<)([^<>]*)(>)", str);
```

result will be: `some text trueString some text`

Comment: just modified in order to make the false case work and NO hardcoded strings

Answer (score 0):

I've to make some prerequisites: some text doesn't contain a matching pair of "<>" brackets.

You can use this code to do your job:

```
var input = @"some text <truestring> <falsestring> some text";
var replacement = match => <some condition> ? match.Groups["truestring"].Value : match.Groups["falsestring"].Value

var regex = new Regex(@"(?:(?:(?<topen>\<)[^\<\>]*)+(?:(?<truestring-topen>\>)(?(topen)[^\<\>]*))+)+(?(topen)(?!))\s*(?:(?:(?<fopen>\<)[^\<\>]*)+(?:(?<falsestring-fopen>\>)(?(fopen)[^\<\>]*))+)+(?(fopen)(?!))");

var result = regex.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Replace some condition with your condition. This regex uses BCD to find the matching bracket of truestring or falsestring so truestring and falsestring are able to contain matching backets.

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
public static string Substitute(string input, bool condition)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"<(?<true>.*?)>\s*<(?<false>.*?)>", m => condition ? m.Groups["true"].Value : m.Groups["false"].Value);
}
```

usage:

```
string input = "The company <is> <is not> a co-owner of other accounts in the Bank.";
string output = Substitute(input, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "some text <trueString> <falseString> some text";
            string pattern = @"(?'beginning'[^\<]+)\<(?'true'[^\>]+)\>\s*<(?'false'[^\>]+)\>(?'ending'[^$]*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            bool condition = true;
            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern);
            string output = "";
            if (condition)
            {
                output = expr.Replace(input, "${beginning}${true}${ending}");
            }
            else
            {
                output = expr.Replace(input, "${beginning}${false}${ending}");
            }


        }
    }
}​
```